# How to add 'screen' blend mode to canvas element?

Tags: css, animation, canvas, adobe, mix-blend-mode

I have an html5 animation that uses two images. The first is a jpg of a woman. The second is a gradient jpg that is layered above the woman and animates over her.

I want the gradient image to be at 50% opacity and have the CSS mix-blend-mode property as “screen”.

It *works great* in **Version A1** (created with Google Web Designer). See Version A1 [here](http://www.clevermill.com/stackoverflow/blendmode/300x600_A1/).

It *does not work* in **Version B1** (created with Adobe Animate CC). The gradient is at 50% opacity but does not have “screen” blend mode because Animate CC’s gui doesn’t support “screen” blend mode. See Version B1 [here](http://www.clevermill.com/stackoverflow/blendmode/300x600_B1/).

I want Version B1 to look like Version A1. I haven't been able to tweak the code to achieve this. Anyone have an idea?

Download the html and image files here: [Download](http://www.clevermill.com/stackoverflow/blendmode/BlendmodeTest.zip).

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="authoring-tool" content="Adobe_Animate_CC">
<title>index</title>
<!-- write your code here -->
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function (cjs, an) {
var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes
var lib={};var ss={};var img={};
lib.ssMetadata = [];
// symbols:
(lib.gradient = function() {
    this.initialize(img.gradient);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Bitmap();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,1070,1339);
(lib.photo = function() {
    this.initialize(img.photo);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Bitmap();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,300,600);// helper functions:
function mc_symbol_clone() {
    var clone = this._cloneProps(new this.constructor(this.mode, this.startPosition, this.loop));
    clone.gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame);
    clone.paused = this.paused;
    clone.framerate = this.framerate;
    return clone;
}
function getMCSymbolPrototype(symbol, nominalBounds, frameBounds) {
    var prototype = cjs.extend(symbol, cjs.MovieClip);
    prototype.clone = mc_symbol_clone;
    prototype.nominalBounds = nominalBounds;
    prototype.frameBounds = frameBounds;
    return prototype;
    }
(lib.PHOTO = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});
    // Layer_1
    this.instance = new lib.photo();
    this.instance.parent = this;
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));
}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.PHOTO, new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,300,600), null);
(lib.hotspot = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});
    // Layer 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f("rgba(65,65,65,0.008)").s().p("EgXbAu4MAAAhdvMAu3AAAMAAABdvg");
    this.shape.setTransform(150,300);
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(4));
}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,300,600);
(lib.GRADIENT = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});
    // Layer_1
    this.instance = new lib.gradient();
    this.instance.parent = this;
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));
}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.GRADIENT, new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,1070,1339), null);
// stage content:
(lib.index = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});
    // timeline functions:
    this.frame_0 = function() {
        this.hotspot.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler.bind(this));
        function fl_MouseClickHandler()
        {
            //Start your custom code here for when the ad is clicked.
            window.open(window.clickTag);
        }
    }
    this.frame_92 = function() {
        this.stop();
    }
    // actions tween:
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this).call(this.frame_0).wait(92).call(this.frame_92).wait(1));
    // hotspot
    this.hotspot = new lib.hotspot();
    this.hotspot.name = "hotspot";
    this.hotspot.parent = this;
    this.hotspot.setTransform(150,125,1,1,0,0,0,150,125);
    new cjs.ButtonHelper(this.hotspot, 0, 1, 2, false, new lib.hotspot(), 3);
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.hotspot).wait(93));
    // GRADIENT
    this.instance = new lib.GRADIENT();
    this.instance.parent = this;
    this.instance.setTransform(535,669.5,1,1,0,0,0,535,669.5);
    this.instance.alpha = 0.5;
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).to({x:-235,y:-69.5},89,cjs.Ease.quartInOut).wait(4));
    // PHOTO
    this.instance_1 = new lib.PHOTO();
    this.instance_1.parent = this;
    this.instance_1.setTransform(150,300,1,1,0,0,0,150,300);
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_1).wait(93));
}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(150,300,1070,1339);
// library properties:
lib.properties = {
    id: '81B93427D538447FB1884A97C84A1343',
    width: 300,
    height: 600,
    fps: 30,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    opacity: 1.00,
    manifest: [
        {src:"images/gradient.jpg", id:"gradient"},
        {src:"images/photo.jpg", id:"photo"}
    ],
    preloads: []
};
// bootstrap callback support:
(lib.Stage = function(canvas) {
    createjs.Stage.call(this, canvas);
}).prototype = p = new createjs.Stage();
p.setAutoPlay = function(autoPlay) {
    this.tickEnabled = autoPlay;
}
p.play = function() { this.tickEnabled = true; this.getChildAt(0).gotoAndPlay(this.getTimelinePosition()) }
p.stop = function(ms) { if(ms) this.seek(ms); this.tickEnabled = false; }
p.seek = function(ms) { this.tickEnabled = true; this.getChildAt(0).gotoAndStop(lib.properties.fps * ms / 1000); }
p.getDuration = function() { return this.getChildAt(0).totalFrames / lib.properties.fps * 1000; }
p.getTimelinePosition = function() { return this.getChildAt(0).currentFrame / lib.properties.fps * 1000; }
an.bootcompsLoaded = an.bootcompsLoaded || [];
if(!an.bootstrapListeners) {
    an.bootstrapListeners=[];
}
an.bootstrapCallback=function(fnCallback) {
    an.bootstrapListeners.push(fnCallback);
    if(an.bootcompsLoaded.length > 0) {
        for(var i=0; i<an.bootcompsLoaded.length; ++i) {
            fnCallback(an.bootcompsLoaded[i]);
        }
    }
};
an.compositions = an.compositions || {};
an.compositions['81B93427D538447FB1884A97C84A1343'] = {
    getStage: function() { return exportRoot.getStage(); },
    getLibrary: function() { return lib; },
    getSpriteSheet: function() { return ss; },
    getImages: function() { return img; }
};
an.compositionLoaded = function(id) {
    an.bootcompsLoaded.push(id);
    for(var j=0; j<an.bootstrapListeners.length; j++) {
        an.bootstrapListeners[j](id);
    }
}
an.getComposition = function(id) {
    return an.compositions[id];
}
})(createjs = createjs||{}, AdobeAn = AdobeAn||{});
var createjs, AdobeAn;
</script>
<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot, anim_container, dom_overlay_container, fnStartAnimation;
function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    anim_container = document.getElementById("animation_container");
    dom_overlay_container = document.getElementById("dom_overlay_container");
    var comp=AdobeAn.getComposition("81B93427D538447FB1884A97C84A1343");
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    loader.addEventListener("fileload", function(evt){handleFileLoad(evt,comp)});
    loader.addEventListener("complete", function(evt){handleComplete(evt,comp)});
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}
function handleFileLoad(evt, comp) {
    var images=comp.getImages();    
    if (evt && (evt.item.type == "image")) { images[evt.item.id] = evt.result; }    
}
function handleComplete(evt,comp) {
    //This function is always called, irrespective of the content. You can use the variable "stage" after it is created in token create_stage.
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    var ss=comp.getSpriteSheet();
    var queue = evt.target;
    var ssMetadata = lib.ssMetadata;
    for(i=0; i<ssMetadata.length; i++) {
        ss[ssMetadata[i].name] = new createjs.SpriteSheet( {"images": [queue.getResult(ssMetadata[i].name)], "frames": ssMetadata[i].frames} )
    }
    exportRoot = new lib.index();
    stage = new lib.Stage(canvas);
    stage.enableMouseOver();    
    //Registers the "tick" event listener.
    fnStartAnimation = function() {
        stage.addChild(exportRoot);
        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
    }       
    //Code to support hidpi screens and responsive scaling.
    function makeResponsive(isResp, respDim, isScale, scaleType) {      
        var lastW, lastH, lastS=1;      
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);        
        resizeCanvas();     
        function resizeCanvas() {           
            var w = lib.properties.width, h = lib.properties.height;            
            var iw = window.innerWidth, ih=window.innerHeight;          
            var pRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1, xRatio=iw/w, yRatio=ih/h, sRatio=1;          
            if(isResp) {                
                if((respDim=='width'&&lastW==iw) || (respDim=='height'&&lastH==ih)) {                    
                    sRatio = lastS;                
                }               
                else if(!isScale) {                 
                    if(iw<w || ih<h)                        
                        sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);              
                }               
                else if(scaleType==1) {                 
                    sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);              
                }               
                else if(scaleType==2) {                 
                    sRatio = Math.max(xRatio, yRatio);              
                }           
            }           
            canvas.width = w*pRatio*sRatio;         
            canvas.height = h*pRatio*sRatio;
            canvas.style.width = dom_overlay_container.style.width = anim_container.style.width =  w*sRatio+'px';               
            canvas.style.height = anim_container.style.height = dom_overlay_container.style.height = h*sRatio+'px';
            stage.scaleX = pRatio*sRatio;           
            stage.scaleY = pRatio*sRatio;           
            lastW = iw; lastH = ih; lastS = sRatio;            
            stage.tickOnUpdate = false;            
            stage.update();            
            stage.tickOnUpdate = true;      
        }
    }
    makeResponsive(false,'both',false,1);   
    AdobeAn.compositionLoaded(lib.properties.id);
    fnStartAnimation();
}
</script>
<!-- write your code here -->
</head>
<body onload="init();" style="margin:0px;">
    <div id="animation_container" style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00); width:300px; height:600px">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="600" style="position: absolute; display: block; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);"></canvas>
        <div id="dom_overlay_container" style="pointer-events:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:600px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: block;">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Animate uses EaselJS, which supports [HTML Canvas `globalCompositeOperation`](https://codepen.io/pen/), which has both pixel composite operations, but also typical blend modes, including "screen".

Since there is currently no Animate support in the IDE (yet, we are hoping for future support), you will have to identify which clip in your library you want to have that blend mode, and set it yourself.

For example, if its the PHOTO instance (which contains the `photo` bitmap), you can set blend mode on the `instance`:

```
(lib.PHOTO = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});
    // Layer_1
    this.instance = new lib.photo();
    this.instance.compositeOperation = "screen"; // <------------------- there
    this.instance.parent = this;
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));
}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.PHOTO, new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,300,600), null);
```

Or, if you want to set it on the entire PHOTO clip on the main timeline (which is your stage/`exportRoot`), you can target `instance_1`:

```
// PHOTO
this.instance_1 = new lib.PHOTO();
this.instance_1.compositeOperation = "screen";
```

Hopefully you get the idea. Unfortunately it will get overwritten when you export it again. You could turn off the html updating in the settings, and set it manually in the HTML code:

```
// Find this:
exportRoot = new lib.index();
// And dig in yourself:
exportRoot.instance_1.compositeOperation = "screen";
```

Hope that helps!